# Error matrix transformation of points in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to transform a 3D model, but it seems to fail and I am trying to investigate what is the reason.

I have one piece of code, which produces a 3D coordinates and a matrix, and multiplies them, and then in WPF I am trying to perform the same operation, but seem to be getting different values.

```
Point3D a = new Point3D(-0.552284, 0.904515, -2.987232);
var matrix1 = new Matrix3D()
        {
            M11 = 1.660177,
            M22 = 1.660177,
            M33 = 1.660177,
            M14 = 0.989035,
            M24 = -0.743628,
            M34 = 4.506998,
            M44 = 1.0000
        };
Point3D b = matrix1.Transform(a);
```

The output of B is as follows:

```
0.0670127994101071
-0.109751653602916
0.362463476775451
```

However, when I do the matrix multiplication just on some random online calculator of:

```
    1.660177 0.000000 0.000000 0.989035
    0.000000 1.660177 0.000000 -0.743628
    0.000000 0.000000 1.660177 4.506998
    0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
```

and

```
-0.552284
0.904515
-2.987232
1
```

I get:

```
 0.072146
 0.758027
-0.452336
 1.000000
```

Am I doing something wrong? This also applies when I try to move the whole 3D model which makes it invisible although it should be correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve it. For some reason the naming ( at least to me) is quite confusing and the indexing as well, but basically had to replace all MX4 with corresponding OffsetX, OffsetY, OffsetZ.

```
Point3D a = new Point3D(-0.552284, 0.904515, -2.987232);
var matrix1 = new Matrix3D()
        {
            M11 = 1.660177,
            M22 = 1.660177,
            M33 = 1.660177,
            OffsetX = 0.989035,
            OffsetY  = -0.743628,
            OffsetZ   = 4.506998,
            M44 = 1.0000
        };
Point3D b = matrix1.Transform(a);
```

Comment: Have you considered using the operation specific transformation classes (`TranslateTransform3D`, `RotateTransform3D`, etc)?  They should eliminate the need to have to deal with the individual raw matrix fields.

Comment: I did, but as an output of an external program, I am getting a homogenous transformation and thus wanted to have it as a single transformation